# countdown error with getElementsByClassName

Tags: jquery, countdown, getelementsbyclassname

I have an error using the `getElementsByClassName`, it does not show me the results you want in my class.
When I use an `getElementbyID` that works smoothly with the class but no way, I have no error in the console I do not understand why the result is not displayed.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product').innerHTML = '<span class="texte_countdown" style="text-align:center;"></span><br/>';
document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product').innerHTML += '<span class="days">'+ days+ '</span>';
document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product').innerHTML += '<span class="hours"><span class="pts_countdown">:</span>' + hours+ '</span>';
document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product').innerHTML += '<span class="minutes"><span class="pts_countdown">:</span>' + minutes+ '</span>';
document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product').innerHTML += '<span class="seconds"><span class="pts_countdown">:</span>' + seconds+ '</span>';
document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product').innerHTML += '<span class="milliseconds"><span class="pts_countdown">:</span>' + milliseconds+ ' </span>'
```

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s82UM/)

Comment: You used the jQuery tag on this question. If you really use jQuery why not use jQuery markup like so: `$('.classname')`
That returns you a list of all jQueryElements in that class.

Comment: Note that getElementsByClassName return a set of elements and not just one ;)

Comment: i dont know how i cant do that..

Comment: What? Use the jquery selector or use an array of elements returned by the javascript function?

Comment: I replaced the getelementsbyclass by $(.classname) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of the selected DOM Element objects, you should iterate through the selected elements and update the `innerHTML` for every selected element. You are adding a `innerHTML` property to the returned Array object which of course doesn't throw an error but doesn't do what you expect.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('countdown_product');
for ( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
   elems[i].innerHTML = '<span class="texte_countdown" style="text-align:center;">text</span>';
}
```

As you are loading jQuery you can select the elements by className and use `html` or `append` method, jQuery uses `each` method behind the scene and updates the `innerHTML` properties for you.

```
$('.countdown_product').html('<element>content</element>');
```

Comment: i try you're solution on my fiddle, but it doesn't work again :@

Comment: I tried your solution with jquery $ ('...) but the result still does not appear

Comment: I love you, I just changed the result of the display and it's perfect! THANK YOU: D